# const is not getting it's initial value

Tags: react-native

i have a constant array in which i push variables and then when i navigate to another page and go back to the first one, i find the same elements in the array the const doesnt get back it's first values.
i need it to be an empty array every time i navigate to that page.
i even tryed to clear it myself in the function cleartab with array.slice with array.filter... but nothing worked for me. this is the code :

```
const array = [];

export default function ScanBarCode({ navigation }) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);

  cleartab= async()=>{
    console.log(array != [])
    await array.map((item) => {
      const valueToRemove = item;
      array.filter(it => it !== valueToRemove);
    });

  }
  const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ type, data }) => {
    await cleartab();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because this constant is initialized with its file only once. To fix your problem you have to clear your array in useEffect's callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
  array.splice(0, array.length); // this line clears array
  (async () => {
    const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === "granted");
  })();
}, []);
```

One more issue:

```
array != [] //always returns true
```

If you want to check whether the array is empty, you should do next:

```
!array.length // return true when array is empty
```